# Adding additional mutable variables in an ERC-20 Token Smart Contract (Extending ERC-20)

Tags: erc-20, inheritance

I am having a question considering inheritance/extending of ERC-20 Token Smart Contracts.

I would like to **add additional mutable variables to an ERC-20 token before the deployment** on the Ethereum Mainnet.

Alongside the defined variables by the interface:

```
name (string),
symbol (string),
decimals (uint8),
totalSupply(uint8)
```

I would like to add additional **mutable variables**, which values could be changed after deployment through transactions. They would look something like this:

```
issuedSupply(uint8),
dedicatedManager(string)
```

I did not find an answer yet in the official specification references:

- https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-20/
- https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

There are two similar questions:

- [Extending ERC-721 with additional functionality](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45770/extending-erc-721-with-additional-functionality)

  - *Says extending is generally possible*
- [Extending Issued ERC 20 Token](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/extending-issued-erc-20-token)

  - *Says extending in ERC-20 is not possible **after** deployment, which makes sense.*

So, to make my question complete:

**Can I implement a smart contract, complying to the ERC-20 standard and having additional parameters which are publicly visible and which values can be changed after deployment through transactions?**

Thanks a lot for having a look at my my question,

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The smart contracts can be extended using the inheritance pattern and you can add additional fields on block storage if you want. You can also update these fields using a transaction. A sample would look like

```
contract ERC20FixedSupply is ERC20 {
    string public test;
    constructor() public {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }
    function setTest(string memory _test) public {
       require( msg.sender == owner, "Should be owner" );
       test = _test;
    }
}
```

In the above example the `setTest` function can be used to set the custom variable `test` and `ERC20FixedSupply` is a ERC-20 Smart contract